# Showing $X$ has finite expectation if $Y$ has finite expectation and $P(|X-Y| \leq M ) = 1$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables such that $$P(|X-Y| \leq M) = 1 $$

for some constant $M$. Show that if $Y$ has finite expectation, then $X$ has finite expectation and $|EX - EY| \leq M,$ where here $E$ denotes the expectation of the variable.

Defining the variable $Z = X-Y$, we see that $P(|Z| \leq M) = P(-M \leq Z \leq M) =1$. Thus $Z$ exhibits the values between $-M$ and $M$.

We then have $EX - EY = E(X-Y) = EZ = \displaystyle\sum_{z}{} z f_Z(z),$ where $f_Z$ denotes the density of $Z$. By the bounds on $Z$, $EZ$ is finite thus $EX = EY + EZ$ is finite.

Also, $|EX-EY| = |EZ| \leq E|Z| = E|X-Y|.$ Since $|Z| \leq M, \ E|Z| \leq M$.

Is this correct?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Shouldn't $\sum$ be $\int$? And what if $X,Y$ are not continuous?

Comment: This is in the chapter on discrete random variables so I guess they implicitly assumed that the variables are discrete. I should have made that explicit, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with:

$\left|X\right|\leq\left|Y\right|+\left|X-Y\right|\leq\left|Y\right|+M$
almost surely, and consequently $\mathbb{E}\left|X\right|\leq\mathbb{E}\left|Y\right|+M<\infty$.

In your question I read: "We then have $\mathbb{E}X-\mathbb{E}Y=\cdots$".

That does not make sense because at that stage a proof that $\mathbb{E}X$ exists has not been given.

Comment: Thanks. Can I change the order and instead start from $EZ$ to show $EZ + EY = EX$?

Comment: Yes. If $Z$ and $Y$ both have finite expectation then you are allowed to conclude that $Z+Y$ has finite expectation as well.